Why does my printf function not work? Is my while loop not ending?
I am just trying to copy and paste the text input. After which the code must show done.
#include <stdio.h>
/*code to copy all input characters and paste it one by one*/
int main()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF)/* while gets a character, assigns it to c and then tests whether the character was EOF,
    if not then the below code is executed*/
    {
        putchar(c);
    }
    printf("Done");
    return 0;
}

It is like my while loop is not ending because, as soon my input is copied, the code asks me for another input. Hence, it is never showing the Done.

Can't reproduce. What is your input, and what OS?

The input is whatever I enter in the command prompt, my OS is windows

I mean, what is you exact input keystoke by keystroke? When I enter a b c <Enter> Ctrl-Z <Enter> the program behaves as expected.

If you're typing input from a terminal, you have to use a special keystroke to indicate end of file. On windows I think it's Ctrl-Z. Are you doing that?

The Ctrl-Z must be the first keystroke of the line and be followed by <Enter>.

Yeah exactly only when I have Ctrl-Z Enter at the end it works. Is there any reason?

That is what it is for. It tells EOF. It marks the end of the input. Whereas <Enter> marks the end of a line.

Ok I think I got it. Thank you

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Avoid some buffering issues printf("Done"); --> printf("Done\n");

"end of file" makes sense if you redirect stdin, but the console does not "end", in any real sense, it is continuous.  So you need a "signal" to terminate input.

See also Canonical vs Non-Canonica Terminal Inputl Input and also while ((c = getc(file)) != EOF) loop won't stop executing.  The latter is not part of your problem — but it is as well to be aware why it isn't.
